# Felt + need/needed

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, backshifting, reported-speech

I came across a sports article which reads,

> Twenty of the 22 players who played in the inaugural day-night Test felt the pink ball **needs** more refinement.

Why is there '**need**'? Shouldn't it be '**needed**' instead ?

Could you tell me when to use present tense or past tense is such situations?

Comment: It should be needed here. 
"20 of the 22 players who played in the inaugural day-night test felt that the pink ball needed more refinement"

Answer (score 1):

It's informal. It's wrong. Some people talk, and even write, like that. But it's still wrong. The correct way of putting it would be:

> Twenty of the twenty-two players who played in the inaugural day-night
>   Test felt the pink ball needed more refinement.

(It's either 20 of the 22, or twenty of the twenty-two. One needs to be consistent. No pun intended).

Comment: I mean, it likely still needs said refinement. Pink balls don't get refined so quickly. That said, it's iffy that the people quoted meant their quotes to be taken as correct at press time, so I definitely agree it should be needed. I just don't think it's incorrect on principle.

Comment: @modulusshift: It is incorrect in principle.

Comment: That's a very reductionist view. Do you often disqualify non-standard tenses for often being incorrectly used, even when there could be cases (though rare) where it might be both intelligible and useful?

Comment: I often make my hardline decisions when reflecting on principles, not in them, as well. I'm sure both are correct, but I would reserve "in principle" for when the principle literally contains the case in question, which is rare. Not good to be too principled, after all. Much better to have a few principles and infer the rest of your decisions from them.

Comment: @modulusshift: My views are my own. I do find it counterproductive to encourage illiterates. In this epoch of aggressive anti-intellectualism things get out of control easily. The right to take a cavalier approach to tenses needs to be earned. An aspiring composer absolutely needs to get his scales down pat before he's allowed to improvise.

Comment: Perhaps, but as a jazz musician myself, I find it a lot easier to pick up scales by instinct instead of by intellect before improvising. Clearly the instinct is there, as we have no shortage of people giving us these incorrect usages for examination. But perhaps you're right, as I am only an amateur saxophonist, and I'm consistently in awe of professionals' solo work.

Comment: @modulusshift : Take another sentence, "Maria said that she likes coffee".  What about this sentence, is it correct to use 'likes' in this sentence ?

Comment: What exactly is the rule that makes it wrong?  I'm asking quite seriously.  My gut feeling is that "needs" is perfectly, because *they felt* (in the past, at the time this happened) that the ball *needs* improvement (that is, that its state was and presumably still is "needing improvement"). If the ball had been refined between those events and now, only *needed* would be appropriate, but if the state of the ball has not changed, it still *needs* improvement. But I acknowledge that this could just be informal use.

Comment: RE: _It's either 20 of the 22, or twenty of the twenty-two. One needs to be consistent. No pun intended_. I love the pun, but there's an exception that applies: Spell out a number at the beginning of a sentence. ([This article](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/rules-for-writing-numbers.html), for example, espouses that rule.) That's not to say that your advice is wrong, but I think the author could justify the original version, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. Remember that you're time shifting the feeling to the time you mentioned it. It's possible that the pink ball has been refined between the time the questions were asked and the time the article was published. The most you can claim is that the pink ball needed refinement at the time.

If it was an implicit or explicit quote, using said or told, then you are free to use the tense they would have used. In addition, if little time has passed, it could be appropriate to keep it in the present tense.

Comment: In regards to your first sentence, you should be a little more clear about what is incorrect here: Is it the original quote? Or the O.P.'s query about, "Shouldn't it be _needed_ instead?"